# Problem with palindrome checker for numbers

Tags: c#, palindrome, error-code

I'm having problem with my code and cannot find my error. Why only the first try is working and on every other tries it prints me false?
Even when I enter `323`, which is true, for example, and prints "true" after that everything is false even empty scapes.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string inputedString = Console.ReadLine();
        string reversedString = string.Empty;

        while (true)
        {
            if (inputedString == "END")
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int i = inputedString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                reversedString += inputedString[i];
            }

            if (reversedString == inputedString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() is not inside the loop, so your program never reads the second line. Put the first two lines of your Main() method inside the loop and you should be good.

Comment: You also initialize the reversedString string outside of the loop

Comment: Essentially what is happening is that inside your while loop, the first time it will check the palindrone "323" correctly. However, you initialize your two `string` variables outside the loop. Therefore, `reversedString` is just being constantly appended to (i.e. `323323323...`). There are some answers below that show you the solution to your problem, but before you fix it, I feel that this would be a good exercise for you to actually step through the debugger and look at the values of `inputedString` and `reversedString` as it loops. It will help you locate errors like this a little easier :)

Comment: This is the kind of error you'd have noticed quickly if you stepped through your code in a debugger the first time you ran it. It's one more thing to learn when you're new to coding, but it's a valuable skill to start building at the same time you're learning to code. Seeing what your code does is educational in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the first string outside the loop and never reread the string inside the loop.  You also don't clear the reversedString so each subsequent time in the loop its wrong.

```
public static void Main()
{
        string inputedString; 
        string reversedString;

        while (true)
        {
            inputedString = Console.ReadLine();
            reversedString = string.Empty;

            if (inputedString == "END")
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int i = inputedString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                reversedString += inputedString[i];
            }

            if (reversedString == inputedString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked.. I knew it would be something stupid (Im new to coding)

Comment: Just an FYI its a good idea in this case to write a function to actually check the for the palindrome and let the code in main drive that function and the loop.  That way you don't have to manage the state of the loop along with the state of the palindrome checker.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the code below should be inside the 'while" loop

```
string inputedString = Console.ReadLine();
string reversedString = string.Empty;
```